# Passing wildcard LIKE parameter to read_sql_query()

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc

Every time I run the code below, I receive an execution failed on sql error.

```
lookup = f'12545%'
sql = pd.read_sql_query(
'''
Select *
From table
Where Name like ?
'''
,conn,lookup)
```

Basically, I think I need the following passed inside the double quotes as a parameter: "'12545%'"

Not sure what the best way there is to do this.

I've tried escaping ' and % but still get the same error or it says none of 12545 exists.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the parameters as a keyword argument, because it's the 5th positional argument to the function.

You have to put all the parameters in a list or tuple, not a single string.

```
ql = pd.read_sql_query(
'''
Select *
From table
Where Name like ?
'''
,conn,params=[lookup])
```